# UIPickerView data fron NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nsdictionary, uipickerview

I have date from web service like this:

```
{
            "idlife_stage_question" = 43;//..basically this should be key
            "life_stage_idlife_stage" = 1;
            "profile_idprofile" = 0;
            "question_text" = "example";//..this should be object
            sequence = 42;
    }
```

Now i need "idlife_stage_question" and "question_text" from each dictionary of JSON and load "question_text" in a UIPickerView and then show the selected row text in a UILabel. Further i need to fetch "idlife_stage_question" for corresponding  "question_text" so that i can send "idlife_stage_question" to server later on. How can i do this with an NSDictionary?

**EDIT:**

My req is:

1. Get "idlife_stage_question" and "question_text" from JSON.
2. Set "idlife_stage_question" and "question_text" in NSMutableDictionary
3. Populate UIPicker with "question_text"
4. Show selected row text in a label
5. Get "idlife_stage_question" fron NSMutableDictionary corresponding to the "question_text" to send it to server.

Comment: consider breaking your question in parts, would be helpful for you as well as to others

Comment: do u mean you have multiple blocks of json like the one youve given? are they an array?

Comment: yes..multiple..that was just a sample

Comment: how are you getting the JSON?

Comment: Using ASIhttpReqquest

Comment: r u getting any results? from the following code?

Comment: Can you check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have `self.questionsArray` which have all the data from webservice and there is only one component in `UIPickerView`

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [self.questionsArray count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   return self.questionsArray[row][@"question_text"];
}
```

The method which dismiss the pickerView

```
- (void)dismissPickerView
{
    //Get the selected Row in picker
    NSInteger selectedQuestionIndex = [self.pickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    NSDictionary *question = self.questionsArray[selectedQuestionIndex];

    self.label.text = question[@"question_text"];

    //Use this value to send back to server
    NSInteger questionId = [question[@"idlife_stage_question"] integerValue];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

parsing json to nsdictionary

```
-(void) requestFinished : (ASIHTTPRequest *) request {
        NSArray *myArray = [NSJSONSerialization 
                                              JSONObjectWithData:[request responseData]
                                              options:kNilOptions 
                                              error:&error];
        }
```

To check you Array hierarchy:

```
NSLog(@"%@", myArray);
```

Now each element of your array can be extracted into NSDictionary. When you iterate your array each object you get is an NSDictionary.

To iterate your array

```
NSEnumerator *myIterator = [myArray objectEnumerator];
    id anObject;

    while( anObject = [myIterator nextObject]){
        NSLog(@"%@", [anObject objectForKey@"question_text"]);
        // get each value of your question_text in a new NSArray and use that array for UIPickerView demostrated in the following link
    }
```

then see [here](http://cocoamatic.blogspot.com/2010/08/create-uipickerview-programmatically.html) how to create UIPickerView programatically